# Error trying to send message in Telegram with Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram-bot

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient();
List<ChannelAccount> participants = new List<ChannelAccount>();
var tBot = new ChannelAccount
{
    ChannelId = "telegram", Address = "9digit", IsBot = true, Id = "salodkid_bot", Name = "salodkid_bot"
};
participants.Add(tBot);
var tUser = new ChannelAccount
{
    ChannelId = "telegram", Address = "9digit", IsBot = false, Id = "dsalodki", Name = "dsalodki"
};
participants.Add(tUser);
Message message = new Message
{
    From = tBot,
    To = tUser,
    Participants = participants.ToArray(),
    Text = "Hey, what's up everyone?",
    Language = "en"
};
var obj = connector.Messages.SendMessage(message);
```

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: The bot ... does not match From:... To:...

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Message.From.Address field needs to contain the bot id, like this:

```
var tBot = new ChannelAccount
{
    ChannelId = "telegram", Address = "salodkid_bot", IsBot = true, Id = "salodkid_bot", Name = "salodkid_bot"
};
```